# In Java's built-in sound framework, can an audio source stream have multiple consumers?

Tags: java, audio

Is there an easy way to have multiple independent, concurrent consumers to an audio source (e. g. a microphone line) inside a single Java VM instance with Java's built-in audio framework (`javax.sound.sampled.*`)? Since I'm using the audio processing library [TarsosDSP](https://github.com/JorenSix/TarsosDSP) anyway, can it be of help with that problem? Or do I need to implement my own audio mixer?

My current problem is, that I want to

1. process an audio stream from a microphone input with [TarsosDSP](https://github.com/JorenSix/TarsosDSP) (to derive a spectrogram amongst other analyses) and
2. record snippets of that stream to transcribe speech to text, which may require watching for volume threshold for automatic activation.

Answer (score 1):

I found [some information](http://www.jsresources.org/faq_audio.html#multiple_tdl_per_card), that partially answers my question:

> **1.3.2. How can I get more than one `TargetDataLine`?**
>
> Current implementations of the Java Sound API do not support multiple `TargetDataLine`s for the same recording source. There are no plans to change this behaviour. If, in the future, multi-channel soundcards are supported, it may be possible to get different `TargetDataLine` instances for the different inputs. If you just want to "split" lines, do it in your application. See also [Can I use multi-channel sound](http://www.jsresources.org/faq_audio.html#multichannel?)

So, that means, that at the time of writing, Java doesn't support multiple consumers on the same recording source and it likely won't be supported in the future. That leaves me to implement my own solution or find a library with an existing solution.